# Bootstrap's js elements are not working even though they were imported

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm to user the collapse feature provided by Bootstrap. Therefore I've installed jQuery and popper.js:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/hover.css/css/hover.css",
    "node_modules/hamburgers/_sass/hamburgers/hamburgers.scss",
    "src/styles.scss"
    ],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
```

**Bootstrap itself is working, but its js elements not, for instance I can't use the collapse features which relies on `data-toggle`.**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"canvasjs": "^1.8.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"hamburgers": "^1.1.3",
"hover.css": "^2.3.2",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"popper.js": "^1.15.0",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"},
```

Does anybody see the issue or has experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap depends on more then just CSS - it also has JavaScript elements. But the problem is, angular doesn't know about that part of JavaScript - and since it's creating the bootstrap widgets on it's own time, Bootstrap JS, even if you include it, will not see it in proper time.

That's why you have to use a dedicated bootstrap library, like [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) or [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) and not bootstrap directly.
So remove jQuery, remove bootstrap, and include one of the Bootstrap libraries for Angular.

Comment: What about the classes I've used so far - will they change?

Comment: Most of them no. You need to read up on the docs on whatever you used before. Also, some things you'll have to adapt, but layout and visual stuff in general remains the same. Try and see what broke :)

Comment: Can I use both bootstrap and ng? Or will this cause issues?

Comment: @Tim if you want to use the css of bootstrap and the features without including jquery and popper then go for ng-bootstrap (for bootstrap 3 and 4 ) other wise if you want to use it in primitive way then you need to use jquery and popper js

Comment: @Tim yes, but as Niladri says, either include ngx-bootstrap for Bootstrap 3 or 4 (or ng-bootstrap, which only supports BS3). Then use trhe components from ngx-bootstrap. Seriously it's easy, go to the sites I linked and look at examples and read - everything is explained well enough. Alternatively you have to write your own JS, or include, e.g. jQuery - _and_ connect it all to your angular code, which will not be easy.